# It can be A or D

Tags: word, enigmatic-puzzle

### I'm looking for a single word. What word is it?

---

```
         •
         x         
          
            
•            x    •



         •

         •
         x      
         x
              
•                 •



         •

         •
              
         x
              
•              'x'•



         •

         •
         x      
       
              
•             x   •



         •

         •
         x      
       x
              
•                 •



         •
```

Comment: Potential [MTC](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7431/monthly-topic-challenge-6-is-it-really-that-time-again?cb=1) submission? (Although I admit that may remove some of the 'enigmatic' element of the puzzle...)

Comment: @Stiv Yes, it would def do that. Even now it was solved pretty fast.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It can be

> **Analog** or **Digital**

And the word you are looking for is

> **Clock**.

We can clearly read the each section

> as a clock.

We have

> the times 3.00, 12.00, 12.'15', 3.00, 11.00

We read them as,

> 3, 12, 15, 3, 11 and convert using A1Z26, and get "CLOCK".

Comment: This is it, well done!